# Need to click submit button twice after setting val() with jquery in custom file upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I'm trying to style an ASP.NET FileUpload control by hiding it and putting in my own controls. I'm doing this with jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=file]').each(function () {
        var fileUpload = $(this);

        var textBox = $('<input type="text">');
        textBox
            .css('width', fileUpload.width() - 85)
            .css('margin-right', 5)
            .prop('disabled', fileUpload.prop('disabled'));

        var button = $('<input type="button" value="Browse...">')
            .prop('disabled', fileUpload.prop('disabled'));

        fileUpload.change(function () {
            textBox.val(fileUpload.val());
        });

        button.click(function () {
            fileUpload.click();
        });

        fileUpload.after(button).after(textBox);
        fileUpload.hide();
    });
});
```

This basically works great, except that I need to click my submit button twice in IE (10). I can't reproduce this in jsFiddle, but I did make [a stripped down ASP.NET project](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8A96FC45CE2F53E7!37075&authkey=!AMUfD_OtWS9iJU8) where it happens.

In Firefox, I don't have this problem. Anyone know where I can start to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabi's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242072/html5-file-upload-form-with-customized-style-cant-fire-submit-button-using-ie10) solved it for me. Possibly, it's some sort of security feature, I'm not sure. But by using a label for the file upload, you only need to click the label once.

You will have to style the label as a button though. There's a great explanation in the jsFiddle. I'm not sure about the remark about Mozilla. It works fine in Firefox for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can't style FileUpload for security reasons in IE, plus the very little changes you can might be different looking in each browser.

A solution which is given me by a friend for my project is to hide the FileUpload and put some image over it. The concept is to give the FileUpload opacity 0 and zindex high and the button zindex low and position absolute.

Here is a code sample from our proj

> .NewInvoiceDialog .AspFileUpload {
>       cursor: pointer;
>       position: absolute;
>       z-index: 1;
>       -moz-opacity: 0.00;
>       opacity:.00;
>       filter: alpha(opacity=00); }
>
> .NewInvoiceDialog .stepBlueButtonWrapper.AddInvoiceFile {
>       float: none;
>       z-index:0; }
>
> .NewInvoiceDialog .stepBlueButtonWrapper.AddInvoiceFile * {
>       z-index:0;
>       cursor:text; }

```
        <div style="position:relative; display:inline-block">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" CssClass="NewInvoiceDialog_AspFileUpload" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <div class="stepBlueButtonWrapper AddInvoiceFile">
                <a><span> בחר חשבונית </span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please read my question entirely. I know the tricks to style a file upload. It's some IE10 behavior I'm having trouble with.