# File Object in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to use the html `input type=file` element and get files from it using `document.getelementbyid("..").files` and it is working fine in chrome and firefox but not in IE 10. I've gone through alot of blogs and most suggest that IE 10 onwards support the File object but its not working for me in either IE 10 or IE 11. Can someone please help me out with this.

code:

HTML: 
`<input type="file" id="fuAttachment" name="fuAttachment" class="mof-strip-file" style="width:68%;" />`

Javascript: 
`var inputfile = document.getElementById("fuAttachment").files[0]; –`

Comment: please share some relevant code in post so that we can help you better.

Comment: @hira Show me your code ??

Comment: @hira Put your code as part of the question not as comment (Remove it from comment)

Comment: @hira Check your error console and try to go through this site maybe useful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @gjman2 i have already been through that site with no help. I was hoping to find a workaround.

Comment: @hira Ic, as I know IE == Problems. Btw can you give me the links of the blogs that said IE 10 onwards support the File object?

Comment: lol.. well it said so on w3c [link]http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: @gjmann also this page is basically the api reference for File api for IE10 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673542(v=vs.85).aspx#api_reference

Comment: @hira try to debug your javascript code.Try to put alert("") in your javascript method then check in your error console.

Comment: @hira maybe useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242072/html5-file-upload-form-with-customized-style-cant-fire-submit-button-using-ie10?rq=1   and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676945/dynamically-submitting-a-file-upload-form-in-ie10-using-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. Turns out that the ActiveX content filtering needed to be turned off in Internet Options > Security. First add your website as trusted site and then select "Custom Level" and then select Disable under ActiveX filtering.